# Spring reactive - backoff breaks chain in retryWhen

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflux

code 1 - with max(3)

```
        Mono.just("abc")
                .map(s -> s.charAt(4))
                .retryWhen(Retry
                    .max(3)
                    .doBeforeRetry(rs -> System.out.println("doBeforeRetry"))
                )
                .onErrorResume(e -> {
                    System.out.println("onErrorResume()");
                    return Mono.just('?');
                })
                .subscribe(System.out::println);
```

Output:

> doBeforeRetry()
>
> doBeforeRetry()
>
> doBeforeRetry()
>
> onErrorResume()
>
> ?

code 2 - with backoff(3, Duration.ofMillis(100)

```
        Mono.just("abc")
                .map(s -> s.charAt(4))
                .retryWhen(Retry
                    .backoff(3, Duration.ofMillis(100))
                    .doBeforeRetry(rs -> System.out.println("doBeforeRetry()"))
                )
                .onErrorResume(e -> {
                    System.out.println("onErrorResume()");
                    return Mono.just('?');
                })
                .subscribe(System.out::println);
```

Output:

> doBeforeRetry()

Looks like backoff breaks a chain completely... The question is why output differs?

Comment: I've tested the second snippet, it produces the right output (same as the first one) on my setup. Questions: 1. the obvious: subscribe is asynchronous. Have you ensured your program has not stopped before the retry happened ? On my part, I've added a `Thread.sleep(1000);` after the snippet. 2. What version of Reactor do you use ?

Comment: You are right program stopped before retry happened - with additional sleep seems to work.
Reactor version : 3.4.24

Comment: Ok, then I suggest that you post an answer yourself, showing how you make it work and what you've learned about the tool. That way, you can close the question as solved and still provide useful insight for future users who would come to this question.